# __repr__ inheritance with pygame.Rec

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

In my test I created a list of instances of class `B`, which inherits from `pygame.Rect`, and has its own `__repr__` method.

When I print the list as `print(blocks)`, it correctly calls the child `__repr__`, but if I print the single elements of the list using a loop, it prints the `__repr__` method of the parent class instead.

Why is this happening?

```
import pygame

class B(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, c):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.c = c
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ColorRect({}, {}, {}, {}, {})>".format(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.c)

blocks = []
size = 1
n = 2
for x in range(0, n*size, size):
    for y in range(0, n*size, size):
        block = B(x, y, 2, 2, (0,0,0))
        blocks.append(block)

# This prints the child __repr__
print(blocks)
# This prints the parent __repr__
for block in blocks:
    print(block)
```

Comment: It's calling _`__str__`_, a list's implementation of which calls `__repr__` on its elements.

Comment: `print(block)` calls the `__str__` method, not the `__repr__` method. So you need to override `__str__` in `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(block)` calls the `__str__` method, not the `__repr__` method. So you need to override `__str__` in `B`.